# Eclipse Cygwin on Windows won't find local library to include?

Tags: c++, eclipse, libraries

I've encountered following problem and can't seem to fix it. Mind you, I'm absolutely new to all this, so please explain everything veery slowly :D

I'm supposed to work on a C++ file. For that, I use Eclipse on Windows with Cygwin. "Regular" C++ code works fine, so there's no problem with the Eclipse/Cygwin-setup per se. However, this particular project comes with a library that I need to include for the code to work. I've tried everything in the Cygwin C++ Linker->Library section but I can't overcome the following error message:

```
g++ -L/cygdrive/c/Users\Katha\eclipse-workspace\Sheet3 -o "Sheet3.exe" ./main.o ./terminal.o   -llibpdcurses.lib
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -llibpdcurses.lib
```

I added the path following this advice:

> if the .lib file is located at : X:\foo\lib\foo.lib, add the library search path (-L) as "/cygdrive/x/foo/lib"

I don't get why it's still not finding the file. Can somebody help?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: The direction of the slashes does not make a difference

Comment: you want just `-lpdcurses`

Comment: The file was originally called pdcurses.lib. Then I read somewhere that it needs to have a lib prefix so I renamed it to libpdcurses.lib. If I don't put the .lib at the end, it tells me that it's skipping the file when searching for it

Comment: Don't use any backslash in the path.

Comment: The file needs to be `libpdcurses.lib`, the command line needs to be `-lpdcurses`

Comment: Changed all backslashes to forward slashes, no difference. @Alan Birtles I changed that, now I get that is it skipping again

Comment: I get this: 
g++ -L/cygdrive/c/Users/Katha/eclipse-workspace/Sheet3 -o "Sheet3.exe" ./main.o ./terminal.o   -lpdcurses
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /cygdrive/c/Users/Katha/eclipse-workspace/Sheet3/libpdcurses.lib when searching for -lpdcurses
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /cygdrive/c/Users/Katha/eclipse-workspace/Sheet3/libpdcurses.lib when searching for -lpdcurses
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lpdcurses

Comment: The library is not compatible with what you're compiling, at a guess its either 32-bit and you're compiling 64-bit (or visa versa) or its a library for a different platform (e.g. Linux or native Windows rather than Cygwin)